# cmake source directory does not exist

Tags: cmake

I am trying to install xtl from [here](https://github.com/QuantStack/xtl). I cloned this directory and unzipped it at this location : /home/usr/Downloads/xtl-master. And then in this directory, I opened up the terminal and entered this command

```
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/fatima/Downloads/xtl-master/CMakeLists.txt
```

And this is the error it gives me :

> CMake Error: The source directory "/home/fatima/Downloads/xtl-master/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/fatima/Downloads/xtl-master" does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to a different directory freshly created for the purpose of building this code, then run this command inside that directory:

```
cmake /home/usr/Downloads/xtl-master
```

Comment: Then move into this new directory and make install ? Or does it take care of it?

Comment: Thanks its done. One last question. I am repeating the same process for https://github.com/QuantStack/xtensor  library and it gives me this error:  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "xtensor" with any
  of the following names:

    xtensorConfig.cmake
    xtensor-config.cmake

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes when you change the directory of source code. you can just add current directory as the source directory in cmake command. modify your cmake command and add option like below to tell current directory is my source directory.

```
cmake -S . Bbuild
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, this is happening because of change of directory path. My advice is to create a new project and just copy your work files.